# Async Task not working?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am creating a weather app and the Async Task isn't working and is causing the app to crash.

Here is the logcat

```
07-19 14:27:06.812 23884-23884/com.oxinc.android.drate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.oxinc.android.drate, PID: 23884
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
at com.oxinc.android.drate.MainActivity.serviceSuccess(MainActivity.java:219)
at com.oxinc.android.drate.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:94)
at com.oxinc.android.drate.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:36)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

And my Async Task

```
package com.oxinc.android.drate.service;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.oxinc.android.drate.data.Channel;
import com.oxinc.android.drate.listener.WeatherServiceListener;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class YahooWeatherService {
    private WeatherServiceListener listener;
    private Exception error;
    private String temperatureUnit = "C";

    public YahooWeatherService(WeatherServiceListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public String getTemperatureUnit() {
        return temperatureUnit;
    }

    public void setTemperatureUnit(String temperatureUnit) {
        this.temperatureUnit = temperatureUnit;
    }

    public void refreshWeather(String location) {

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Channel>() {
            @Override
            protected Channel doInBackground(String[] locations) {

                String location = locations[0];

                Channel channel = new Channel();

                String unit = getTemperatureUnit().equalsIgnoreCase("f") ? "f" : "c";

                String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\") and u='" + unit + "'", location);

                String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(endpoint);

                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);

                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result.toString());

                    JSONObject queryResults = data.optJSONObject("query");

                    int count = queryResults.optInt("count");

                    if (count == 0) {
                        error = new LocationWeatherException("No weather information found for " + location);
                        return null;
                    }

                    JSONObject channelJSON = queryResults.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel");
                    channel.populate(channelJSON);

                    return channel;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    error = e;
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Channel channel) {

                if (channel == null && error != null) {
                    listener.serviceFailure(error);
                } else {
                    listener.serviceSuccess(channel);
                }

            }

        }.execute(location);
    }

    public class LocationWeatherException extends Exception {
        public LocationWeatherException(String detailMessage) {
            super(detailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help. This has been an issue of mine for the past couple day. And I am really struggling to solve it. Which is why I came here!

Comment: The `ImageView` reference in `MainActivity` that you're calling `setImageDrawable()` on in the `serviceSuccess()` method is null.

Comment: @MikeM what should I do to make this work then?

Comment: Figure out why it's null, and fix it. You might just need to initialize it. The post linked in the duplicate banner will help you to track down exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help